# Instagram Login authentication in Flutter

Tags: authentication, flutter, oauth-2.0, instagram

I used package - simple_auth_flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/simple_auth_flutter) for this. But there it require some field called - 'redirect URL'. But how to acquire that? 
**How to set the RedirectURL?**

And when I used Google Account Login with this, it opens a webview and then after logged, it do not close that and do not recieved the token. And there also it required a RedirectURL?

**How to get those URLs? Please explain me on hoe to do that?**